# Failed to open page after cloning Symfony PHP project

Tags: php, symfony

I just cloned a Symfony PHP project from Github but whenever I open a page containing the following code:

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $modules = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Module')->findAll();

    return $this->render('module/index.html.twig', array(
        'modules' => $modules,
    ));
}
```

The page will return the following error:

ConnectionException: An exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database ''.

I am not really experienced with PHP Symfony projects yet and someone asked me to clone this and try to solve the error I will be returned with. Where do I need to look in order to fix the error? I suppose some sort of configuration file which points to database configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error mean you didn't got access to the database.

Run `php app/console doctrine:database:create` and after, `php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force`.

It will create the database on your own local server. (make sure to provide correct connection details on your app/parameter.yml file)

EDIT: Also, don't forget to update your project using `composer install` and `composer update`.
Since this is a github project, all dependencies are not pulled

Comment: Whenever I run `php app/console doctrine:database:create` it will return: `Could not open input file: app/console` how come?

Comment: `php -v` runs just fine, which I think is weird, ain't it?

Comment: Are you sure you are using Symfony2 and not Symfony3? (Symfony3 need to use this cmd as `php bin/console doctrine:database:create`

Comment: I think the project I cloned is a Symfony2 project.

Comment: Check your composer file. Also, Symfony3 got a var and bin folder, which Symfony2 didn't got. (root folder)

EDIT: Run a composer update. From github, useless file aren't uploaded, so you need to update your lacal projet

Comment: Running `composer install` and `compser update` did not solve both those problems. Composer file looks okay aswell (compared to a working project). Not sure what I'm missing out on. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Do you have a console file in your app directory? Also, in your composer.json file, what is your symfont version? ('symfony/symfony:' line)

Comment: I do not have a console file in my app directory. composer.json Contains: `"symfony/symfony": "3.0.*"`.

Comment: Because this is a Symfony3 project. In this case, you need to use `php bin/console doctrine:database:create`. Note that the app has been replaced by bin, because of the new Symfony file structure.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create database:

For **Symfony2**:

```
php app/console doctrine:database:create
```

For **Symfony3**:

```
php bin/console doctrine:database:create
```

You can see **sql dump**:

For **Symfony2**:

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql
```

For **Symfony3**:

```
php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql
```

Than create tables:

For **Symfony2**:

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:create
```

For **Symfony3**:

```
php bin/console doctrine:schema:create
```

Comment: The Symfony 3 command work also for Symfony 6+ FYI :)